# Python-tesseract installation on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to install python-tesseract 0.9-0.5  from a deb file on Ubuntu 15.04, but it gives several errors.
This is what I do:

1- I open the path of the file on terminal and write

```
sudo dpkg -i python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

2- After this, the console shows several errors:

```
Selecting previously unselected package python-tesseract.
(Reading database ... 349994 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb ...

Unpacking python-tesseract (0.9-0.5ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tesseract:
 python-tesseract depends on python (<< 2.8).
 python-tesseract depends on python (>= 2.7~).
 python-tesseract depends on liblept4.
 python-tesseract depends on libopencv-core2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-core2.4:i386 is not installed.
 python-tesseract depends on libtesseract3; however:

dpkg: error processing package python-tesseract (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 python-tesseract
```

3- Just for checking, I open the installation file and extracted the tesseract.py class, and used alone in python.
I opened it this way:

```
python tesseract.py
```

, but I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tesseract.py", line 28, in <module>
    _tesseract = swig_import_helper()
  File "tesseract.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _tesseract
ImportError: No module named _tesseract
```

The thing is that I want to use tesseract functions on python for an optical character recognition application, and I have understood that the best wrapper for this is python-tesseract (is not the same that pytesseract, I think).

My question is: How can I to install python-tesseract on Ubuntu 15.04? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works installing gdebi-core first, and afterwards installing the .deb package with it, so that gdebi install dependencies for me. I used Ubuntu 14.04.

```
 sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
 sudo gdebi python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: I tried but I got:

sudo gdebi python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
gdebi error, file not found: python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb

Answer (score 4):

```
 sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

**After Entering this command in terminal it will install tesseract **

Comment: Working on a raspberry pi 4, the pip install did not succeed but this answer worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update and install tesseract-ocr**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

**Install pytesseract for python**

```
pip3 install pytesseract
```

**Usage**

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img= "path/img.jpg"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img))
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to get python to use Tesseract, I found this [tutorial](http://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/#more-706) which was pretty useful. 
But I then found out that this was way too simple for my needs, so I will need to find a another solution.

I hope this is going to help you man!

Comment: I found an answer that I already posted. Maybe using python-tesseract satisfies your needs, it seems very good. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Use this link for installation](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/tesseract-ocr-installation-and-usage-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

once you do that,
here is the code

```
from PIL import Image
img="pathToYourImage/img.jpeg"
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img))
print(text)
```